# Аутентификация через ВК в asp.net core web api. Как правильно реализовать?

Tags: c#, vue.js, vkontakte-api, oauth, asp.net-core-webapi

Я пишу приложение. Серверная часть представляет собой web api на asp.net core, а клиентская это vuejs приложение. Передо мной стоит задача реализовать вход пользователя на сайт через ВКонтакте.
На бэкенде используется пакет [AspNet.Security.OAuth.Vkontakte](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Vkontakte/)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddVkontakte(builder =>
        {
            builder.ApiVersion = "5.130";
            builder.ClientId = Configuration["ClientId"];
            builder.ClientSecret = Configuration["SecureKey"];

            builder.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize";
            builder.TokenEndpoint = "https://oauth.vk.com/access_token";

            builder.Scope.Add("friends");
            builder.Scope.Add("offline");
        });
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WeAgree", Version = "v1" });
    });
}
```

Не понимаю, как правильно реализовать логику аутентификации пользователя в контексте web api.
Как правильно передать запрос на аутентификацию с фронтенда на сервер и как сообщить фронтенду, что всё прошло успешно или же наоборот ?

Comment: Так, ок, а что мешает почитать документацию? Ведь Microsoft любезно расписали, [максимально подробно](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio), как и что делать.

Comment: Это да. Я же уточнил, что не понимаю, как это сделать, когда у тебя бэкенд и фронтенд разделены. У МС все примеры для MVC. Я новичок и пока не знаю, как адаптировать этот пример под web api.